# Homomorphisms of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove each function is a homomorphism. Describe its kernel and range.

I realize this is two questions but they are very similar so I put them together.

1. $h: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathcal {M}_2(\mathbb R)$ given by $h(x)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
      x & 0\\
      0 & 0 \\
     \end{array} } \right]$

I have begun by saying Let $a=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and $b=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   y & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$.

Now $h(a)h(b)= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   y & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   xy & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ which I believe is the same thing as $h(ab)$.

Now $h(a)+h(b)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]+\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   y & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x+y & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ which I again believe to be the same as $h(a+b)$.
Thus $h$ is a homomorphism. The kernel is when $x=0$ thus $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$.

2. $h: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathcal {M_2}(\mathbb R)$ given by $h(x,y)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
      x & 0 \\
      0 & y \\
     \end{array} } \right]$

For this one let $a=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 0 \\
   0 & y \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and $b=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   w & 0 \\
   0 & v \\
  \end{array} } \right]$.

Now $h(a)h(b)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 0 \\
   0 & y \\
  \end{array} } \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   w & 0 \\
   0 & v \\
  \end{array} } \right]=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   xw & 0 \\
   0 & yv\\
  \end{array} } \right]$ which I believe to be the same as $h(ab)$.

$h(a)+h(b)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 0 \\
   0 & y \\
  \end{array} } \right]+\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   w & 0 \\
   0 & v \\
  \end{array} } \right]=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x+w & 0 \\
   0 & y+v \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ which I believe to be the same as $h(a+b)$.

Thus $h$ is a homomorphism. The kernel here is when $x,y=0$.

For ranges of matrices, is this the same as the range of a function, i.e. for 1, the range of $h$ is all real numbers?

Comment: Alls good so far, other than you forgetting about the range of the homomorphisms

Comment: @mdave16 I apologize I meant to ask about them in my question. I will edit.

Comment: Homomorphism between what structures? Rngs? Also, the range is a subset of the codomain. So the range of your first map would be the set of matrices with all entries equal to zero except for the top left entry. And the range of the second map would be the set of all diagonal matrices.